# Electrical Characteristics of Toshiba Mosfets

Tags: transistors, mosfet, power-electronics, inverter, datasheet

I have been Searching for power mosfets for designing an inverter. One crucial parameter I was looking for is the Rds_on relationship with junction temperature.
Other manufacturers (infineon, Irf, ST) seem to provide a graph of Rds_on with respect to Junction temperature.
Oddly toshiba's datasheet seems to specify the Rds_on wrt to ambient temperature.
[image]

The above graph was taken from TK65A10N1 mosfet's datasheet.
All toshiba's mosfets seem to specify their temperature dependence like this.

How would one extract information about Rds_on wrt to Junction temperature.
A case can be made that using thermal impedances the junction temperature could be extracted. But power dissipation is not known.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's stated as a pulse test, so you can assume Tj \$\approx\$ Ta.

Comment: Could you elaborate please?

Comment: The pulse is assumed to be short enough that the junction temperature remains at ambient (close enough).